# MySQL table split

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with about 20 columns. 10 of them generally tend to have 1 of 15 or so possible values (different for each column). In addition, one column has a largish string. The table currently has over 3 million rows, and growing. It is about 1GB big (just data)

1. I would like to split off the large text column, since it is not used often and would probably dramatically reduce the table size, thus improving performance.
2. I would like to "normalize" all those repeating columns into a separate table (each), so that I can get the list of current values without running 10 `distinct` queries on 3M rows. It takes a long time.

#2 would be one-to-many relations. #1 could be 1-to-1 or 1-to-many. I don't care.

The question is: Can these be done by pure SQL statements? How? Or do I need to write a program to put the data in the new table and get the PK and insert it in the right column, one row at a time?

**Edit**
Here is a sample of what I am trying to do:

```
ID  Field1  Lookup  Text
10  val1    look1   some very long text
11  val2    look2   more very long text
12  val2    look1   NULL
13  val4    look1   some very long text
.
.
.
```

To this:

```
ID  Field1  Lookup  Text
10  val1    1       1
11  val2    2       2
12  val2    1       0
13  val4    1       4 (1?)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the point 1, it's a one-to-one relationship, so you don't need a foreign key (instead, you'll use the same primary key for both table).

1. Create your table `mytable_text` with a PK of the same type (not in auto increment of course), your TEXT column, and, if you're using InnoDB (which is recommend in this case) a foreign key to your first (main) table. You could add ON DELETE CASCADE to the foreign key to ease the maintenance.
2. `INSERT INTO mytable_text (id, large_text_column) (SELECT id, large_text_column FROM mytable)`
3. `ALTER TABLE mytable DROP large_text_column`

For the point 2, it's a bit longer, but it's also doable in SQL (I'm taking the example of your field "Lookup"). It could be something like that:

1. Create your secondary table "lookups" with an autoincrement ID, and a field "title" for example (with a UNIQUE INDEX if you feel like it).
2. `INSERT INTO lookups (title) (SELECT DISTINCT Lookup FROM mytable)`
3. `SET foreign_key_checks = 0`
4. `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD lookup_id INTEGER UNSIGNED [...], ADD FOREIGN KEY [...]`
5. `UPDATE mytable SET lookup_id = (SELECT id FROM lookups WHERE lookup.title = mytable.Lookup`
6. `ALTER TABLE mytable DROP Lookup`
7. (optionally) `ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE lookup_id Lookup [...]` (if you want to keep the same name)
8. `SET foreign_key_checks = 1`

Comment: I edited my answer based on your example. Note that with 3M rows the alter statements can take some time.